# Three-column GridView: one with only text, the other two with checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I'm having trouble binding values to checkboxes and, subsequently, checkboxes to the GridViewColumn. Basically, I have three columns named Property, Tele, and Surr respectively, and I have a list of objects of type Row. Row has three properties: Name (string), Tel (bool) and Sur (bool. I want to populate Property with all the Names (and that seems to be working fine, via a DisplayMemberBinding), and the other two columns with checkboxes whose states correspond to the values of Tel and Sur.

Where am I going wrong?

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         Margin="0,0,-8,0">

<Grid x:Name="GView" Margin="0,0,-8,0">
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="114.99,12.96,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="DefaultName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175.01"/>
    <Label Content="Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <ListView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=rows}" 
              x:Name="LView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="159" Margin="0,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="Property" 
                                Width="100" 
                                Header="Property"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="Tele" 
                                Width="100" 
                                Header="In Tele?"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Tel}">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="telCheck" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Tel}}"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="Surr" 
                                Width="100" 
                                Header="In Surr?" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Sur}">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="telCheck" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Sur}}"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**XAML.CS:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<Row> rows; 

    public ObservableCollection<Row> Rows
    {
        get { return rows; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        rows = new ObservableCollection<Row>();
        rows.Add(new Row("item1", true, false));
        rows.Add(new Row("item2", true, true));
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

}

**Row.cs:**

```
public class Row : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private bool _tel;
    private bool _sur;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
                return;
            _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public bool Tel
    {
        get { return _tel; }
        set
        {
            if (_tel == value)
                return;
            _tel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Tel");
        }
    }
    public bool Sur
    {
        get { return _sur; }
        set
        {
            if (_sur == value)
                return;
            _sur = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Sur");
        }
    }

    public Row(string name, bool value, bool value2)
    {
        Name = name;
        Tel = value;
        Sur = value2;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Not sure why you would be using DisplayMemberBinding. Try removing the DisplayMemberBinding and change IsChecked="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Tel}} etc to IsChecked="{Binding Path=Tel} etc.  Once you've set the DataContext to your collection, you should only need to set a simple binding path on the templates.

Comment: Wait, it isn't working again... What I currently have is <ListView DataContext="{Binding ElementName=rows}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=rows}" and then <CheckBox x:Name="telCheck" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=Tel}"></CheckBox>

Comment: I usually set the datacontext in code-behind... in the XAML I will set ItemsSource = "{Binding}" and in the code-behind set LView.DataContext = rows (not necessarily in the constructor, but always chronologically after InitializeComponent)

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes in your code and got it working.

First of all, don't populate your rows collection in the window constructor, do it after the window is loaded. Unfortunately i couldn't bind the collection to the grid `ItemsSource` in xaml, so i did it in the codebehind, after filling the collection. And using `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=rows}"` was not correct just because `rows` collection is `private`, you need `puplic` collection named `Rows`.

And another thing - to get your checkboxes to show as checkboxes instead of a text:

1. Remove `DisplayMemberBinding` from Tele adn Surr column definitions
2. Instead of `IsChecked="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Tel}}` use `IsChecked="{Binding Tel}` and same for Sur